# Extract text before backslash in R

Tags: r, string, extract

In R, I have code that contains this column of text:

[image]

In the Player column, I only need the text before the backslash.

**Desired output**

Joey Votto

Juan Soto

Charlie Blackmon

Freddie Freeman

**Here is the dput result**

```
structure(list(Player = c("Joey Votto\\vottojo01", "Juan Soto\\sotoju01", 
"Charlie Blackmon\\blackch02", "Freddie Freeman\\freemfr01"), 
    TOB = c(321, 304, 288, 274), TB = c(323, 268, 387, 312), 
    G = c(162, 151, 159, 162), WAR = c(8.1, 7.1, 5.5, 5.5)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I would prefer a code that works in R with dplyr.

I have tried to get it to work with this code, but it did not work:

```
mutate(Name = str_extract(Player, "(?=\\)"))
```

I have looked at the solutions Stackover suggested, but did not see one that fit my situation. If there is one that I missed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `str_remove` to match the `\\` and remove the rest

```
library(stringr)
 str_remove(str1, "\\\\.*")
[1] "Charlie Blackmon" "Freddie Freeman"
```

---

If we use in `tidyverse` syntax

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(Player = str_remove(Player, "\\\\.*"))
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Player             TOB    TB     G   WAR
  <chr>            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Joey Votto         321   323   162   8.1
2 Juan Soto          304   268   151   7.1
3 Charlie Blackmon   288   387   159   5.5
4 Freddie Freeman    274   312   162   5.5
```

---

Or using `base R` with `trimws`

```
 trimws(df1$Player, whitespace = "\\\\.*")
[1] "Joey Votto"       "Juan Soto"        "Charlie Blackmon" "Freddie Freeman"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Charlie Blackmon\\blackch02", "Freddie Freeman\\freemfr01")
```

Answer (score 2):

From R 4.0.0, you can use raw strings, so no need for double backlashes, just use the following syntax: `r"(your_raw_expression)"` (parentheses included). Here we can do:

```r
str_remove(df$Player, r"(\\.*)")
# [1] "Joey Votto"       "Juan Soto"        "Charlie Blackmon" "Freddie Freeman"

str_extract(df$Player, r"(^.*(?=\\))")
# [1] "Joey Votto"       "Juan Soto"        "Charlie Blackmon" "Freddie Freeman"
```

Comment: The second solution -- ```str_extract(df$Player,r"(^.*(?=\\))")``` generates an error in RStudio on the line containing it when it is embedded in ```mutate(Player=str_extract(df$Player,r"(^.*(?=\\))"))```; however, you still get the correct result.

Comment: You should rather specify the dataframe before like so `mutate(df, Player=str_extract(Player,r"(^.*(?=\\))"))`

Comment: I am piping the dataframe. ```stkov %>%
  mutate(Player=str_extract(stkov$Player,r"(^.*(?=\\))"))```

Comment: Then `stkov %>%   mutate(Player=str_extract(Player,r"(^.*(?=\\))"))`. Don't mention the dataframe once again when it's piped

Comment: that is how I am doing it.

Comment: The code in my last comment does not work?

Comment: The code works despite the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `stringr::str_extract`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Player = c("Joey Votto\\vottojo01", "Juan Soto\\sotoju01", 
"Charlie Blackmon\\blackch02", "Freddie Freeman\\freemfr01"), 
    TOB = c(321, 304, 288, 274), TB = c(323, 268, 387, 312), 
    G = c(162, 151, 159, 162), WAR = c(8.1, 7.1, 5.5, 5.5)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df %>% 
  mutate(Player = str_extract(Player, "^.*(?=\\\\)"))

#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   Player             TOB    TB     G   WAR
#>   <chr>            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Joey Votto         321   323   162   8.1
#> 2 Juan Soto          304   268   151   7.1
#> 3 Charlie Blackmon   288   387   159   5.5
#> 4 Freddie Freeman    274   312   162   5.5
```

Comment: Given that all that needs to be found is the first backslash to know which text to either extract or remove, why do most solutions contains four backslashes?

Comment: Thanks for your question. Well, in your `dput` data, there are _two_ backslashes (and not only one), @Metsfan: `"Joey Votto\\vottojo01"`. That is why.